# Let Artifactory use HTTPS settings

Tags: ssl, https, artifactory

If I want users to use HTTPS to Artifactory UI, how should I set it up?
I refer to: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-debug-ssl-issues-with-artifactory/ssl-certificate-issues-from-artifactory-perspective

But no success.

I entered https://FQDN:8443 and "HTTP 404" appeared. I'm not sure what went wrong. The following are the settings I made in system.yaml:

```
artifactory:
     tomcat:
         httpsConnector:
             ## Enable connector with SSL/TLS
             enabled: true
             ## Port to use for the HTTPS connector
             port: 8443
             ## Certificate file to use
             certificateFile: "/tmp/arti.crt"
             ## Certificate key file to use.
             certificateKeyFile: "/tmp/arti.key"
```

Please ask if you can provide some suggestions, thank you.

Users can connect directly to Artifactory using HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to have users connect to Artifactory over SSL is to use a reverse proxy with SSL termination configured on the reverse proxy.

This page gives some more information: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/configure-nginx

The steps you should take using Nginx are:

1. Install Nginx
2. Configure your settings in the Artifactory UI to generate the reverse proxy  snippet.
3. Insert the snippet into the sites enabled or conf.d folder and reload nginx.

More full instructions for these steps can be found here: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/reverse-proxy-settings

There is an option to enable TLS directly on Artifactory without a reverse proxy. This has many requirements and should only be done if your companies security policy needs all internal communication to be over TLS.

Instructions for this can be found here:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/set-tls-on-the-jfrog-platform